# Why do images in Jekyll collections appear in the site root directory?

Tags: jekyll

I have a Jekyll project setup using multiple collections to group documents together. My `_config.yml` looks like this:

```
collections:
  course001:
    output: true
    title: "Theme structure"
    relative_url: "/theme-structure"    # The subpath of the the site, 
    permalink: /theme-structure/:name
```

The directory structure of the `course001` collection looks like this:
    course001/
        index.md
        figures/
            figure01.jpg

The the generated HTML looks like this:

```
_site/
    figure01.jpg
theme-structure/
    index.html
```

Instead of the expected:

```
_site/
    theme-structure/
        index.html
        figure01.jpg
```

Why does the image appear in the site root folder? I do not want the images to appear in the root folder due to potential for name collision. This is only a problem for images, not documents which end up in the expected place.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Seems irrelevant ot your question but it's not. Are you using collection for only one item or do you want to display several items inside that collection? Because , if you are going to create several collections `course001`, `course002`, etc. it's better to group them inside a collection `courses`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this it's what you really looking for. Anyway, I propose you a new structure for your project supposing that you are going to create a lot of courses each with its own lectures. If you have also sub-lectures the code is easy to expand and handle them.

The first thing is your `_config.yml` file. You should create two collections for courses and lectures (unfortunately Jekyll doesn't handle sub-collections).

```
collections:
  courses:
    output: true
  lectures:
    output: true
```

You have to create both `_courses` and `_lectures` folders.

In the `_lecture` folder you should put the markdown files of your lectures. Each lecture should have a tag for the course it belongs to. I also add a tag for the lecture to facilitate the handling of paths. This is an example of a lecture file with an image.

```
---
layout: lecture
title: My first lecture
course: 001
lecture: my-first-lecture
---
This is my first lecture!!

![fish][fish]

[fish]: assets/img/{{page.lecture}}/fish.png
```

As you can see you need a folder `assets` in your `_lecture` folder. You could use the file `lecture.html` in your `_layout` folder to contain your template. The following one is just an example and basically is the same as a `page` layout.

```
---
layout: default
---
<article class="post">

  <header class="post-header">
    <h1 class="post-title">{{ page.title | escape }}</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="post-content">    
    {{ content }}
  </div>

</article>
```

Now you need to group them by courses. Unfortunately, as I previously stated, Jekyll doesn't handle nested collection so we check the tag `course` in each lecture to see what are the lecture in each course. Thus if you want to type a list of lectures at the beginning of each course page then you should have a file `_layout/course.html` similar to

```
---
layout: default
---
<article class="post">

  <header class="post-header">
    <h1 class="post-title">{{ page.title | escape }}</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="post-content">

    <ol>
    {% for lecture in site.lectures %}
    {% if lecture.course == page.course %}
      <li><a href="{{lecture.url}}">{{lecture.title}}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </ol>

    {{ content }}
  </div>

</article>
```

A typical markdown file for a course should be stored in `_courses` and will be similar to

```
---
layout: course
title: My first course
course: 001
---
This is my first course!!
```

The only thing left is a page to show the list of your courses. You could create a `coursed.md` file in your project folder with this content.

```
---
layout: page
title: Courses
permalink: /courses/
---

These are my courses:

<ol>
{% for course in site.courses %}
  <li><a href="{{course.url}}">{{course.title}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

I know that this probably is more than what you asked in your question and you still wonder why the strange behavior. I think that this is due to the fact that you should store the files that you want in your built site in an assets folder. This is the only way (I think, but maybe I'm wrong). I'm not referring only to the `assets` folder in your main directory but also to the `assets` folders in your collection's directories.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed response. I tried renaming the `figures` folder to `assets` and found that it made no difference. I did find out that this behaviour only occurs when the permalink value is `theme-structure/:name`. Using `theme-structure/:path` this does not occur (I've updated the question).I'm intrigued by your suggested structure changes. But I don't understand what the advantage would be? It would make the _config.yml simpler I guess, but not sure it would help otherwise.

Comment: I don't know if this could be best structure for your project. I should know more on what you want to do. The basic difference is that this structure allows you to fake multiple nested collections and also a lecture could belongs to multiple course. while with yours you are stuck at one level collections (of course, if that's what you need the there is no need to change).

Comment: This is a terrific explanation.  OP should accept it.

Comment: @cryptic0 Unfortunately I didn't even get the point of the question. :(

Comment: New users of jekyll are often unaware of the `assets/` location for static files you want copied under `_site`.  I was the same way.  Your answer helped me organize my data analysis notes.

Comment: @cryptic0 I'm glad to be helpful to someone from time to time. :)